# Need a Context-Free grammar with 5 times as many of one character as the other

Tags: context-free-grammar, pushdown-automaton

I'm pretty sure I've actually got one, but it has 42 construction rules and doesn't generalize well. How can I do it with fewer construction rules?

The language is {a,b}* where the number of a's is five times the number of b's.

I know that for a language {a^n (concatenate) b^m; m = 5n} it would just be

> S = aSbbbbb | λ

But when the characters can be in any order, I'm lost.

Comment: Do you have evidence that it is possible to express the grammar with a few rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, observe that if a sentence has 5 times as many characters as the other, it'll always look something like `aaabaabaaaaa`. So one sentence can be `aaaaab` or `aaabaa`. Another observation is that whenever we add a `b`, we must add five `a` characters.

The following grammar indeed has five times as many `a` characters as `b` characters:

```
S = AS | λ
A = Baaaaa | aBaaaa | aaBaaa | aaaBaa | aaaaBa | aaaaaB
B = bS | Sb
```

We start with `S` which can either by empty (which satisfies the requirement) or `A`.

The rule for `A` produces at least 5 `a` characters and a `B`. Now for `B`, we can either place `b` and stop there (by choosing the empty string for `S`) or by starting again (by choosing `A` for `S`). This guarantees that we're always placing 5 times as many `a` characters as `b` characters.

Lastly, this grammar can easily be generalized to a grammar than needs to contain `n` times as many characters of one as the other (by straightforwardly extending rule `A`).

Comment: I don't know what you just said, but you used a character I don't know how to do with a keyboard, so it must be right.  +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am not sure that this is correct. I can not figure out a way to derive, for example, baaaaaaaaaab from those rules. My apologies if I am overlooking something. Can you see a way to derive baaaaaaaaaab? It seems only possible to get a b on one end of the string.

Comment: You're right, I couldn't find a way to derive either `baaaaaaaaaab`. I've adjusted the rule for `S` to make it possible: `S` = `AS` = `AAS` = `AA` = `BaaaaaA` = `BaaaaaaaaaaB` = `bSaaaaaaaaaaB` = `bSaaaaaaaaaabS` = `bSaaaaaaaaaab` = `baaaaaaaaaab`.

Comment: Beautiful, I think it works. Thanks! Don't think I ever could have come up with that >.<